# Screaming Frog Lighthouse Java Lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: api, pagespeed

I keep getting these errors on every single PSI (page speed insights) API request.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 2899 column 25 path $.lighthouseResult.audits.dom-size.details.items[0].value

Is this a lighthouse issue or is indicating something is broken within the page?

I tried to use the page speed ingishts api in screaming frog to get page speed insights across the site and it keeps giving me this error regardless of which website i test it on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the save error until I restarted Screaming Frog SEO Spider and updated to 18.4